# php function to convert "04-05-2012" to "04/05/2012?

Tags: php, date

I have tried using `date("m/d/Y", strtotime("04-05-2012"))` but I will get `"05/04/2012"` or on some other dates for example `"03-30-2012"` I will get `"12/31/1969"` (which makes sense because it it mixing up the month and day and there is no 30th month. So how  should I do this? I also want to then convert the value into a UNIX time so that I can search it against MySQL db.

Comment: `str_replace('-', '/', '04-05-2012')`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date format for db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697609/convert-date-format-for-db)

Comment: Different countries have wildly different ideas about whether you should start with month or day.  Is 04-05-2012 April 5th, or May 4th?  Even Canada and USA have differing views on that one.  Probably a better idea to switch to YYYY-mm-dd as your format.  It also sorts better.

Comment: `03-30` is march 30th, not the 3rd of month 30.

Comment: I think I will do what @ghoti mentioned and use YYYY-mm-dd, I think it will work for what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `explode()` and `mktime()`:

```
$inDate = '03-30-2012';
list($m, $d, $y) = explode('-', $inDate);
$outDate = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
```

This assumes the format is somehow dynamic, though.  Otherwise, `str_replace()` is your best option, as others pointed out.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the DateTime object and createFromFormat static method to do it :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',"03-30-2012");
$date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: That looks really helpful but we're using PHP 5.1.6 and that function wasn't implemented until 5.3.0.

Comment: perhaps a migration would be cool. We're now on php 5.4, and php 5.3.10 is out with more than 1,000 bug fixes and perf improvement. And some feature additions like DateTime, Intl...

Answer (score 6):

If you know for certain that the format you start with is DD-MM-YYY when why not use a simple replace?

e.g. `$newDate = str_replace('-', '/', '04-05-2012');`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a date format question as a string manipulation question.

But it's still good to know that **[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)** exists.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat transdate.php 
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$olddate = "04-05-2012"; // assuming mm-dd-YYYY

// Get the date parts into an array
$parts = explode("-", $olddate);
// Switch to YYYY-mm-dd, which will be interpreted consistently
$neworder = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", $parts[2], $parts[0], $parts[1]);

printf("New order: %s\n", $neworder);

// Set your timezone, or PHP will whine and complain
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
// Convert your reordered date to an epoch second (unix timestamp)
$epoch = strtotime($neworder);

// At a terminal, `man strftime` (or read the PHP function's docs) for details.
print "Alternate formats:\n";
printf("\t%s\n", strftime("%D", $epoch));
printf("\t%s\n", strftime("%F", $epoch));
printf("\t%s\n", strftime("%A %B %e, %Y (week %U)", $epoch));

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./transdate.php 
New order: 2012-04-05
Alternate formats:
        04/05/12
        2012-04-05
        Thursday April  5, 2012 (week 14)
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

This will work in PHP 5.1.6.  Heck, it should work in PHP 4, except for `date_default_timezone_set()`.